# How can I upload a file to a pCloud folder using python?

Tags: python, cloud-storage, pcloud

Files only upload to the root folder:

```
from pcloud import PyCloud

pc = PyCloud('username','password')

pc.uploadfile(files = ['pics\\img.png'])
```

I couldn't find any arguments like *destination* or *dest*.

Comment: The github docs state "path='/path-to-pcloud-dir')" - give that a go!

Comment: Wow, thank you soooooooooo much! =D

Answer (score 1):

you could do like the following:

```
from pcloud import PyCloud

pc = PyCloud('username','password')

pc.uploadfile(files=['/full/path/to/image1.jpg', '/Users/tom/another/image.png'],
              path='/path-to-pcloud-dir')
```

Reference: [pcloud - A Python API client for pCloud](https://github.com/tomgross/pycloud)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use all methods the [pClooud API](https://docs.pcloud.com/methods/file/uploadfile.html) provides.

Both

```py
>>> pc.uploadfile(files=['/full/path/to/image1.jpg', '/Users/tom/another/image.png'],
                  path='/path-to-pcloud-dir')
```

and

```py
>>> pc.uploadfile(files=['/full/path/to/image1.jpg', '/Users/tom/another/image.png'],
                  folderid=0)
```

are possible.